# Getting Dates from URL in PHP and Refreshing Page

Tags: php, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to display a line chart that gets it's data from a PHP service that runs a query based off the dates entered. The Query works and it's getting the data however when trying to pass my dates into the url and get the chart back with the data I can't seem to wrap my brain around how to just "refresh" the chart without leaving that page because when I submit my form or "date fields" it just goes to the service url.... Here is what I'm experiencing.

This is what I include on my index page that actually displays the chart:

```
  function drawChart() {
      var jsonData1 = $.ajax({
          url: "http://helpdesk/reporting/interface/charts/services/ticketsopenedclosed.php?startDate=<?php print $startDate = $_GET['startDate'] ?>&endDate=<?php print $endDate = $GET_['endDate'] ?>",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
```

Here is where I actually have my form (the same page that has the chart that I want to refresh with the data from the form!!)

```
<div><form action="charts/ticketsopenedclosedchart.php" method="get"><div class="well">
            <input type="text" class="span2" value="startDate" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dp2" name="startDate">
            <input type="text" class="span2" value="endDate" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dp3" name="endDate">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Refresh Data</button></div></form>
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>

   </div>
    <?php require("charts/ticketsopenedclosedchart.php")?>
    <div id="ticketsCreated"></div>
```

So with this obviously when I click the submit button it hits that url and gives dates and the data from the service. But I want to refresh my chart with that data not take the user to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you submit the form, the browser will natively go to the URL specified in the action attribute. To workaround this, you need an onClick handler on the button.

So something like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onClick="handleRefresh">Refresh Data</button>
```

And then the JS:

```
function handleRefresh(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    drawChart();
}
```